# Find using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to change the background color of '.preview-inner' to yellow from "#change_color"?

```
<div id = "form-container>
  <input class="color-picker" id="change_color" type="text">
  <div class="replacer">
    <div class="preview">
      <div class="preview-inner" style="background-color: white">
```

I have tried this:

```
$('#change_color').find('.preview-inner').css('background-color', 'yellow')
```

but this has not work.

Note: I am using a plug-in and therefore can not arrange #change_color to be a true parent of '.replacer'

Any ideas?

Comment: why from `#change_color` ?

Comment: because the way the plug in works, the background-color is actually manipulated into the input. (spectrum.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve you r issue you need to select the parent then use your find. Right now you are selecting an element with no children and looking for a specific child, that wont work.

Try this:

```
$('.replacer').find('.preview-inner').css('background-color', 'yellow')
```

Or you can try this:

```
$('#form-container').find('.preview-inner').css('background-color', 'yellow')
```

jQuery find looks for children of the element you have selected. I have create a fiddle to show this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2295Lah/

You may also want to make sure you have jQuery document ready function if your code loads in before your html.

Comment: opps, sorry. thanks for pointing this out. i've updated the selector. it's still .preview-inner

Comment: I edited my response, please review, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible

```
<div id = "form-container">
  <input class="color-picker" id="change_color" type="text">
  <div class="replacer">
    <div class="preview">
      <div class="preview-inner" style="background-color: white; height: 50px; width: 200px;">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#change_color').parent().find('.preview-inner').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
</script>
```

I specified the width and height of the div so you can see the color changed, because if you just define a empty div without dimension and contents you cannot see it.

http://jsfiddle.net/L16kpksz/

Answer (score 0):

An input would never be a true parent to nested divs. You should just be selecting `.preview-inner` with a normal selector `$('.preview-inner').css('background-color', 'yellow')` If you are using farbtastic then I would suggest you take a look at their demos because you aren't getting the grasp of how it works. http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/

Comment: thanks russell. the problem with this solution is there's 10+ '.preview-inner' and i don't want them all to be yellow. i just the one input above it which i am assuming is not possible.

Comment: also, i'm using spectrum.js (not farbtastic)

Comment: Then you would need to first get the parent of the siblings and then do a find from there. You aren't going to find it through the input selector. Good luck!